# Implementing queue in c#

Tags: c#

I am developing a c# application, in which the server gets requests from many clients at a time. Each client also gets their data from different databases.  In this situation sometimes data leakage is happening, means clients get data from an incorrect database.  Say for example client1 should get data from db1 and client2 gets data from db2.  Instead they get data from opposite databases; client1 gets from db2 and client2 gets from db1.
I am adding the code below where it collects the data.

```
public string List()
{ 
    Response.ContentType = ContentType.Xml;

    try
    {
        ThingzFilter filter = null;
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (Id!="")
        {
            // get parameters from http request
            foreach (HttpInputItem param in Request.Param)
                parameters.Add(param.Name, param.Value);

            setServerURLs();
            //Request.Clear();

            if (Request.QueryString["lang"].Value != null)
            {
                ThingzDB.TzThing.get_language = Request.QueryString["lang"].Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ThingzDB.TzThing.get_language = SessionDatabase.DefaultLanguage;
            }
        }

        ThingzDatabase db = SessionDatabase;

        langStr = db.Language;

        // this is run if there was no ID supplied
        // which means we want all items of all types
        if (Id == "")
        {
            if (Request.AcceptTypes == null)
            {
                //TypeController.session_id = Request.QueryString["sessionid"].Value;

                jobs.Add(Request.QueryString["sessionid"].Value);
                if (nextJobPos > jobs.Count - 1)
                    return "";
                else
                {
                    TypeController.session_id = jobs[nextJobPos];
                    nextJobPos++;
                    langStr = SessionDatabase.Language;
                }

                filter = new AllThingzFilter(SessionDatabase, parameters, langStr);
                TypeController.session_id = "";
                filter.Execute();
            }
```

In this server is console application and clients are windows where the site names , means the databse names are mentioned.
Please give me a solution to overcome this issue.

Comment: Hard to figure out your problem. Because the DB-related problems are mostly not an issue of the client-side solely.

Comment: Actually problem with session id, based on the session id only it gets the data.

Comment: Quick tip: when checking for an empty string, such as with your `if-statement`: `if (Id!="")`; you should really use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(...)` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(...)`.

Comment: Is this multithreaded? Maybe you have a race condition. While you got the session_id for client1, and trying to get the data for him, client2 joins in and overwrites the session_id.

Comment: Where is "SessionDatabase" stored?

Comment: Incidently, I don't see how the title relates to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without precisely knowing how `SessionDatabase` is scoped (from the name it seems to be a session variable) or whether it's implementation is a property that does some kind of complex logic, I would guess you have two problems:

- Storing the value at the wrong scope with multiple clients accessing it
- Using `db` and `SessionDatabase` interchangeably in your code.

For the latter, I would suggest `db = SessionDatabase` once at the top of the code (making sure that `SessionDatabase` was the right thing for that client, and then using `db` for the rest of the method.